# How does it ensure that one node is an ancestor and not a sibling?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve [this LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-ancestor/):

> Given the root of a binary tree, find the maximum value V for which there exists different nodes A and B where V = |A.val - B.val| and A is an ancestor of B.  (A node A is an ancestor of B if either: any child of A is equal to B, or any child of A is an ancestor of B.)

One of the [highly upvoted answers](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-ancestor/discuss/274610/JavaC%2B%2BPython-Top-Down) is as below:

```java
public int maxAncestorDiff(TreeNode root) {
    return dfs(root, root.val, root.val);
}

public int dfs(TreeNode root, int mn, int mx) {
    if (root == null) return mx - mn;
    mx = Math.max(mx, root.val);
    mn = Math.min(mn, root.val);
    return Math.max(dfs(root.left, mn, mx), dfs(root.right, mn, mx));
}
```

This is basically just a preorder traversal of the tree. I am unable to digest how it ensures that node `A` is an ancestor of node `B` (and not a sibling)?

Comment: In the recursive tree traversal algorithm you included, it is not possible to access the sibling of a node. Note that the algorithm returns the maximum of the result from the left tree and right tree. As such, the left and right tree are never able to 'interact', so to speak.

Comment: @Arch2K, could you please elaborate your first statement - _"it is not possible to access the sibling of a node"_?

Comment: The algorithm shown updates the max and min at the present node, and then recursively calls the function on the left subtree and right subtree with the updated values of max and min. After obtaining the return value for the right and left subtrees, it returns the maximum of the two. In this context, for every call of dfs, the node in question only updates the max and min values and its left and right subtree. No code here is written such that the node is able to access its sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down.

You are correct that this is just a pre-order transversal. What's important is that for each node we have a minimum value and a maximum value. These values get smaller and larger respectively as we iterate down the tree. At any one given node, we only update `mn` and `mx` with the value of that node. As a result when we pass `mn` and `mx` to the children, those values are only reflective of nodes in the tree up to the current node.

Perhaps  these comments will illustrate this better:

```
public int dfs(TreeNode root, int mn, int mx) {

    // this is the base case, at some point mn was encountered and mx was encountered
    // on the path to this node, this is the maximum possible difference along that path
    if (root == null) return mx - mn;

    // on our current path through the tree, update the max / min value we have encountered
    mx = Math.max(mx, root.val);
    mn = Math.min(mn, root.val);

    // the mn and mx at this point are only reflective of this node and it's ancestors
    // integers are immutable so a function call down the line won't change the 
    // mx and mn here, but rather create a new mx and mn at that node
    // we pass the updated mx and mn to the node's children, exploring paths
    // down the tree

    return Math.max(dfs(root.left, mn, mx), dfs(root.right, mn, mx));
}
```